# How can I add IAM role for other project service account in Google Cloud in different project using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, terraform-provider-gcp

To be Specific, I have two projects A and B. I want to add an IAM role to service account from project A in Project B.  I'm executing terraform script from bitbucket pipeline

Below is the resource block I tried to implement.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "role1" {
  project = var.project
  role = "roles/dialogflow.admin"
  member = "user:cui-server-service-account@cproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

project is the variable used for Project B and cproject is a variable used for Project A which I'll pass the project names during bitbucket pipeline execution.

Answer (score 2):

`member  = "serviceAccount:<<service account email>>"`

The prefix is to be `serviceAccount` rather than `user` from your example - [see how the member/members argument is described](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/google_project_iam#member/members)

And check that the user (or service account) who (which) runs the terraform 'apply' - has relevant IAM roles to assign what you would like.